# Data Structure about struct array

Tags: c, data-structures

Recently, I took a subject called Data structure. I've created a program to try out my knowledge but don't know why the program did not work. I can't figure it out so I post it here to ask for solution. I hope people can help me. I am newbie here. So please ignore my opinion if my opinion is found annoying.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    struct Book
    {
        char title[50];
        int year;
        float price;
    };
    int i;

    struct Book books[50];
    books[0].title="Bullshit";
    books[0].year=132;
    books[0].price=146.9;

    books[1]=(struct Book){"Money",1344,189.4
    };

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("Book Title is : %s\n",books[i].title);
        printf("Book Year is %d\n",books[i].year);
        printf("Book price is %3.2f\n",books[i].price);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: 13 16 D:\data structure code\Module self check 2.6.c [Error] assignment to expression with array type

Comment: Please [edit] the question with all relevant data (e.g. Compilation errors) instead of adding them in the comments.

Comment: _`books[0].title="Bullshit";`_ Really?

Comment: That should be `strcpy(&books[0].title[0], "Bullshit");` If you want to use assignment, switch to `std::string`.

Comment: `books[1] = {"Money",1344,189.4f};` you can initialise this directly

Comment: your books title suggests you are reading the wrong books. Try one of those instead : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 I would make declaration of struct rather outside main than inside

2 Try changing `char title[50]` to `char *title`

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Book {
    char *title;
    int year;
    float price;
};

int main() {

    int i;

    struct Book books[50];
    books[0].title = "Bullshit";
    books[0].year = 132;
    books[0].price = 146.9;

    books[1] = (struct Book) {"Money", 1344, 189.4
    };

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("Book Title is : %s\n", books[i].title);
        printf("Book Year is %d\n", books[i].year);
        printf("Book price is %3.2f\n", books[i].price);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

Why it didn't worked before?

In c arrays are not assignable by `=` operator.
You could do something like instead `title[0] = 'B'; title[1] = 'u', etc...`.(`or use strcpy which does it for you`).

`char *x` is not really an array, it's just pointer to single char.
If we write `x = "abc"`,  we are telling the compiler: set x to 'a', next byte to 'b', next to 'c', and next to 0(not '0', just zero).

And when you do `printf("%s",x)`, the `printf` function prints chars from the place in memory specified by x until it see 0 byte.

```
char *x = "abcd";

char *y = x;
while(*y != 0){   // this loop acts like printf("%s",x);
    printf("%c",*y);
    y++;
}
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186765/what-is-the-difference-between-char-array-vs-char-pointer-in-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867437/char-array-not-assignable) question.

Or if you are using c++, not c, use std::string:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

struct Book {
    std::string title;
    int year;
    float price;

    Book(std::string t, int y, float p) {
        title = t;
        year = y;
        price = p;
    }
};

int main() {

    int i;

    Book books[50];
    books[0].title = "Bullshit";
    books[0].year = 132;
    books[0].price = 146.9;

    books[1] = Book(std::string("Money"), 1344, 189.4);

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("Book Title is : %s\n", books[i].title.c_str());
        printf("Book Year is %d\n", books[i].year);
        printf("Book price is %3.2f\n", books[i].price);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are suggesting a change to `title` data structure, recommend `std::string`.

Comment: Also, the OP could use `strncpy` rather than assignment or changing the array to a pointer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes, of course std::string, but this guy is writing in c, not c++(hmm... he didn't gave any information about it, but his code is more like c code than c++, that's why I didn't use std::string)

Comment: @JK Well, if he would be writing in C, the question would be tagged as C, instead of C++.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Original question hasn't got any tag about language, this tag has been added by edit.

Comment: @JK Interesting.. Then, I would question the decision to replace C tag with C++ tag..

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius First, I've tagged it c++ because it was like c++ code. Then I noticed it's rather c code, but my second edit wasn't accepted.

Comment: @JK Well, edit history shows you adding a C tag, and someone else replacing it with C++ tag.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius my question was made before that edit. And now i've also posted c++ code.

Comment: Your second code does not produce desired result, because `books[i].title` is now a `std::string`, it does not print well with `printf` unless it is a `.c_str();`

Comment: sorry for late reply. But i am studying C instead of C++. Sorry if i do not tag it. But I tried d change char title[50] to char *title . It works. But i still dun know the concept. What is the difference? Can someone explain to me ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope you are the tutor in my university.

Comment: Btw, why scanf("%s",title); works ?Why char title[9]="Bullshit"; works?Why char title[9]; title="Bullshit"; does not works? They looks like same.

Comment: @TeoPeiShen You can write `char title[] = "Bullshit"`, and it means "create a string array that have length of 'Bullshit' string and insert it here." By writing `char title[9] = "Bullshit"` you are saying "create a string array that have length 9 and insert 'Bullshit' here." This is array initialization. "They looks like same." but they aren't. Second one(I mean code from your comment, not mine) is initialization, third one is assignment.

Answer (score 0):

this

`books[0].title="Bullshit";`

is not valid. title is defined as `char[50]`. Either do

```
strcpy(books[0].title, "BS");
```

This will copy the bytes of BS to title. Or do

```
 struct Book
    {
        char *title;
        int year;
        float price;
    };

...
  books[0].title = strdup("BS");
```

This sets title up as a pointer to a char string. strdup will allocate space for the string and copy BS to that space. You will have to free that allocated space.

Or - the best. Use std::string

```
 struct Book
    {
        std::string title;
        int year;
        float price;
    };
....
   books[0].title = "BS";
```

And as a final thought - life goes better with std::vector instead of raw arrays

Comment: "And as a final thought - life goes better with std::vector instead of raw arrays" - 100% agree ;)

Comment: std::vector and std::string are c++ things. I see the tag has been changed to c. SO ignore those suggestions